# CircleCi phpunit test fails to create database.sqlite

Tags: laravel, phpunit, circleci

I am running my tests in CircleCi using the following command:

```
./vendor/bin/paratest
```

I am using this over phpunit as it runs the tests across the available CPU resource, in our cirle instance this is 36 cores, so it should run fairly quickly.

However when I run with that command I get the following errors when the test suite tries to run the migrations

```
Database (/home/circleci/laravel/database/database.sqlite) does not exist.
```

This error does not happen when I use phpunit like this:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit -d memory_limit=2048M
```

Is there an extra step I need to create the database file before running that command?

*The only other change I had to make was to switch all the tests to use `DatabaseTransactions` rather than `RefreshDatabase` for paratest to work

Comment: How do you instantiate the db in your setup?

Comment: I don't, when I run phpunit I am assuming that it's doing it for me

Comment: What about your database configs? Do you want it to run in memory or file?

Comment: I don't mind either, I'd just like it to run

Comment: post your database configs? you want it to run with sqlite as the database i asume?